# How use count query in lambda expression

Tags: entity-framework

I have written a lambda expression and produce the results below.

**Result**

```
    GroupId GroupName
    1   network.it
    1   network.it
    1   network.it
    2   software.it
    2   software.it
    2   software.it
    2   software.it
```

After getting the above result I want to convert above data by using `Count` and `GroupBy` through lambda expression like following.

**Desired Result**

```
    Group Id, GroupName, Count
    1         network.it  3
    2         software.it  4
```

I hope anyone can answer as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to use GroupBy clause

```
var result = from d in data
             group d by d.GroupId into g
             select new {g.Key, g.First().GroupName, g.Count()}
```

Comment: Please help by using lambda expression. And see my desired result. Iam sorry it does not produce the result which I want as I explained above, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but in case someone else comes across this looking for the same information, the lambda way would be

```
var result = Data
             .GroupBy(d => d.GroupId)
             .Select(d => 
                 new 
                 { 
                    GroupId = d.Key, 
                    GroupName = d.FirstOrDefault().GroupName, 
                    Count = d.Count()
                 });
```